# NGINX query string doesn't pass to $_GET

Tags: nginx, xampp

I am moving my webapp from Apache to NGINX under AZURE.
The folder structure is

```
- public/
  - index.php
  - group.php
- inc/
  - group/
    - router.php
    - body.php
    - body_inc.php
```

When I get URL as `https://group?page=2` then my config works fine and I have available `$_GET['page'] = 2`.When I go to `https://group/body_inc` the flow is `index.php->group.php->body.php->router.php->body_inc.php.` I would like to get to the point where `https://group/body/body_inc?page=2` would serve me `$_GET['page'] = 2` as well.

My previous .htacces was defined as

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And now my NGINX config is

```
add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/, HttpOnly, Secure";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains, SameSite=strict";

#
# HTTPS SERVER
#
server {

    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    
    #
    # DEFAULT DOCUMENT ROOT
    #
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    
    #
    # BASIC CONFIGURATION
    #
    server_name *.azurewebsites.net www.*.azurewebsites.net;
    port_in_redirect   off;
    server_tokens      off;
    absolute_redirect  off;

    #
    # GENERATE X-VAR TO HEADER FOR NONCE USE
    #
    add_header X-var $request_id;
    include fastcgi_params;

    #
    # URL LOCATIONS SETUP
    #
    location / {
        index index.php;
        
        # REWRITE URL RULES
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri$is_args$args;
        
        #UTF-8 CHARACTERS
        charset UTF-8;
        
        # CSP NONCE 
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_ID $request_id;

        # SECURE COOKIE
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";

        # UPLOAD FILES UP TO 100MB
        client_max_body_size 100M;

    }
    
    #
    # REDIRECT SERVER ERROR PAGES TO STATIC PAGE /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /html/;
    }
    
    #
    # DISABLE GIT DIRECTORY
    #
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    
    #
    # LOCATIONS OF PHPMYADMIN
    #
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param                   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param                   QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout            3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout            3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
        fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
    
            # HIDE PHP HEADERS
            fastcgi_hide_header             X-Powered-By;
            fastcgi_hide_header             X-CF-Powered-By;
    }
   }
```

Can someone please advise where I have the root of misfunction?
Thank you

I've tried to fiddle with fastcgi params but it seems my config is wrong.
defining `location /group/` or similar is not a option because there are multiple folder like Group in use. I've also tried

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
}
```

but it didn't work for me aither.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri$is_args$args;
```

When request URL is `https://group/body/body_inc?page=2`, the last part in above becomes:

```
/index.php?url=/body/body_inc?page=2
```

`$is_args` is `?` when there are arguments, otherwise it is empty.

This does not work correctly, as the separator for multiple query arguments is `&`.

There is a workaround as follows:

In the `http` level, define a map to get the proper separator:

```
map $is_args $extra_args {
    ? &;
    default '';
}
```

Then, use it in `try_files`:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$url$extra_args$args;
```

Then the resulting URL will be correct and the `$_GET` array should get properly populated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution even without map.
That works for me perfectly.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri$args;
set $args &$args;
```

Thanx to Tero for the tip!